# Excel lookup returns error unless done at specific row in sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

A few colleagues and I are working of copies of the same document and we've all experienced this problem (in excel 2003).

Said document looks up information from a different external excel spreadsheet (via index-match).

The lookups yield a "#value" error, except when they are placed in row 138 or below. Once the table of lookups was moved to row 138, the problem was miraculously solved.

My question then is: does anyone know why this happens? And how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance

The formula is:

```
=INDEX('*lookup sheet*'!$P$1:$P$65536,MATCH($C474,'*lookup sheet*'!$B$1:$B$65536,0),'*lookup sheet*'!$B$1:$B$65536)
```

Note: Column B contains product names and Column P contains prices in the lookup sheet. The formula looks up the product in the lookup spreadsheet and returns the price. The cell to match is in this case C474 but this is because (for example) the formula doesn't work on cell C5. Both tables are populated lengthwise i.e. new products are entered in new columns, and new prices along the same row as the corresponding product.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is, and google hasn't been much help. This is just how I usually write the formulae.

Comment: You do not need the third criterion in the index/match `=INDEX('*lookup sheet*'!$P$1:$P$65536,MATCH($C474,'*lookup sheet*'!$B$1:$B$65536,0))`